# Soil I need and water for drinking

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Soil I need and water for drinking,
>
> 48 chromosomes but none for thinking,
>
> Covered in eyes but never blinking.

**What am I?**

Comment: This was inspired by the classic riddle "Alive without breath/ As cold as death/ Never thirsty, Ever drinking/ Clad in mail, Never clinking" The last line 'Covered in eyes but never blinking" popped into my head and inspired the rest of it.

Comment: What's the answer to *that* riddle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> **[A potato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato)**

Soil I need and water for drinking,

> Potatoes come from soil and need water as they are plants

48 chromosomes but none for thinking,

> Potatoes have 48 chromosomes but don't think as they have no brains

Covered in eyes but never blinking.

> Potato eyes are tiny holes from which sprouts grow

Comment: It's more specific than that ... (**Edit**: Beastly's original answer was "a plant", but he must have edited just before I submitted this comment.)

Answer (score 7):

More specific than (the original version of) Beastly's answer, it's

> a potato.

*Soil I need and water for drinking,*

> Potato plants need soil and water to survive.

*48 chromosomes but none for thinking,*

> [Potatoes have 48 chromosomes](https://www.reference.com/science/many-chromosomes-potatoes-2a7745ffe38993e7), but they don't think because they're plants.

*Covered in eyes but never blinking.*

> Potatoes have [eyes](http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/outdoors/gardening/what-are-potato-eyes), but they don't blink because they're plants.

Comment: Oh I edited to that

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Damn your ninja edits! :-P